# how to read subject of gmail ruby using Ruby Gem -gmail

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gmail

I am trying to figure out how to read body of gmail using Ruby Gem "gmail"
I need to read past 10 days mails and make the objects as Json format

here is the code

```
require "gmail"
date1 = Date.today - 10
gmail = Gmail.connect("mailid", "password")
emails = gmail.inbox.emails(:after => date1)

emails.each_with_index do |mail, i|

#code
#mail.raw_message.body.decoded

end
```

Any suggestions how to read subject and body of mail

Thank you.

Comment: looks like there are methods called `#subject` and `#body` for a `Mail` Object. have you tried them? Also you could see what prints out if you call `emails.first.methods.sort - Object.methods` this will show you a list of the instance methods for a `Mail` Object and they usually have pretty explanatory names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mail is instance of email, for reading subject:

```
mail.subject
```

for reading body

```
mail.body.raw_source
```